# Determining a complex function represented as a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, geometric-series

> Find the domain $D$ of the function
>
> $ f(z) = \sum (-1)^n(z-1)^n - \sum i^{n-1} (z-i)^n $
>
> Then determine $f(z)$, for all $z \in D$

I figured for the first part of the function i could use the sum of an infinite geometric series and we get:

$ \sum (-1)^n (z-1)^n = \frac{1}{2-z}$ since we can ignore the alternating aspect, as it doesnt interfere with the convergence.

However, I'm stuck on how I'd apply the same method to the second part of the function, and definining the domain.

Any help would be hugely appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that each sum separately has a radius of convergence of $1$; thus, the domain of convergence is the intersection of the disks $|z-1| \le 1$ and $|z-i| \le 1$.

[image]

Within this domain, the sums converge to

$$f(z) = \frac1{1+z-1} + i \frac1{1-i(z-i)} = \frac1z -  \frac1{z+i 2} = \frac{i 2}{z (z+i 2)}$$

Comment: Did you get ROC of the second sum as 1, because $|i| = |0+1i| = 1$?

Comment: @GregoryPeck: yes

Comment: Doesnt the first sum converge to $\frac{1}{1-z+1}$ and the second sum converge to $\frac{1}{1-z+i}$? I'm a bit confused as to how you determined the value of $f(z)$

Comment: @GregoryPeck: in the first sum, the $(-1)^n$ factor forces us to use the $+$ sign in the denominator.  In the second sum, I put an extra factor of $i$ in the sum to get the summation indices to line up properly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm wondering though why you multiplied the second sum by $i$ instead of $\frac{1}{i}$, since we changed $i^{n-1}$ to $i^n$ inside the summation.

Comment: @GregoryPeck: I did.  Note the change in sign.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I left the $\frac{1}{i}$ in and got a different answer. I went back and did it your way but  got $\frac{1}{z}$ instead of $\frac{1}{z+i^2}$. The denominator should go to $1-iz+i^2 = -iz$, yes? Apologies and thanks for the help.